# Tkinter: в ScrolledText разместить текст не с первой строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть код:

```
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
text1 = tkst.ScrolledText(root, width = 95, height = 13)
text1.place(x=8, y=8)
text1.insert('1.0','check_me' + '\n')
```

`insert` размещает тест в первую строку, а если например я хочу текст `check_me` разместить в третью строку, а первые две- оставить пустыми? есть способ? (менять `1.0` пробовал, в документации этого не нашел)

Comment: ну естественно можно предложить костыль) `"\n\ncheck_me"`

Comment: не, костыль это не для нас)))

Comment: Дело в том, что строки появляются после выполнения insert. Если вставок ещё не делалось, то третьей строки просто не существует.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял из документации метод insert() вставляет текст по индексу но 
        с поправкой на ветер т.е. как сказал  Sergey Gornostaev если индекс 
        существует.

```
from tkinter import Tk, mainloop, Text
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

app = Tk()

text = ScrolledText(app, width = 100, height = 400)
text.place(x=8, y=8)

for x in range(30):
    text.insert("{0}.0".format(x), '\n')

text.insert(3.0, 'check_me')

app.mainloop()
```